# Инициализация константных полей класса через this

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, константа

```
class X {
    const int a,b,c;
public:
    X (int a,int b, int c);
};
X::X(int aa, int bb, int cc) :a(aa), b(bb), c(cc) {};
```

Как для этого класса написать конструктор, только через указатели `this`,     вроде этого:

```
 X(int a, int b ,int c)
 {
     this->a=a;
     this->b=b;
     this->c=c;
 }   // Этот код не работает, если поля класса константные
```

Comment: А почему вас не устраивает первый вариант? Зачем this?

Comment: чтобы в принимаемых параметрах не писать новые имена

Comment: Никак. Первый вариант для того и предназначен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X(int a, int b ,int c):a(a),b(b),c(c)
{}
```

Этот код совершенно корректный, потому что области видимости членов класса в списке инициализации и аргументов конструктора разные.

Так что вы можете использовать те же имена параметров, что и полей - здесь нет никакой ошибки или неоднозначности.

Comment: Это пример хрупкого кода, стоит только кому-нибудь начать править код изменив среди прочего имя аргумента и забыв исправить инициализацию поля - сразу вылезет дефект. А если он еще в теле конструктора как-то используется, то будет совсем весело.

Comment: @VTT Пример не `хрупкого` варианта можете предоставить?

Comment: @vegorov Обычно имена полям класса выбираются так, чтобы они не совпадали с именами локальных переменных. Допустим, с префиксом `m_`. Это тоже не панацея, но все же лучше.

Comment: @VTT А, всё, я понял о чём вы. `X(int x, int y ,int z):a(a),b(b),c(c)` - вот об этом ? Тогда да, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A 
{ 
   const int a; 
   A() : a(0) 
   { 
      this->*(int A::*)&A::a = 1; 
   } 
} a;
ASSERT (a.a == 1);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это ж неопределенное поведение, разве нет?

Comment: От чего же? Всё вполне определено: сначала обычная инициализация нулём (без неё никак, она обязательная), а потом доступ через указатель на член. Ему то как раз константность отменить вполне можно, всё по стандарту.

Comment: `всё по стандарту` звучит неправдоподобно. Пруф? Особенно хотелось бы увидеть послабление для следующего пункта стандарта языка: [dcl.type.cv / 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4), `Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior.`

Comment: Ааа, вы не о синтаксическом стандарте... Это предупреждение связано с особенностями оптимизации.  Типа, компайлер может использовать значение константы вместо самой константы, а если бы константа не была членом класса - компилятор мог бы вообще не размещать её в памяти. Но это крайне старая дыра, и не осталось в природе компиляторов, которые не учитывают прямое "деконстантирование" указателя. Обнаружив такое, любой компилятор прекращает агрессивную оптимизацию для константного объекта. Ныне, чтоб нарваться на эту дырку - нужно репозиционировать указатель на константный объект. Так что сойдёт.

Comment: `не осталось в природе компиляторов, которые не учитывают прямое "деконстантирование" указателя` [Уверены](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ca214e335539469)?

Comment: Признаю, не знал, что в восприятии компилятором константных переменных и константных полей класса такая большая разница. Тут вообще не в оптимизации дело (хоть всю вырубай) Просто компилятор воспринимает обычную константу как какой-то литерал, и пихает всюду её значение. А вот к константному полю класса всегда идёт обращение по адресу. Это именно восприятие синтаксиса, а не особенности платформ. Самое странное, что что константная переменная в памяти всё таки размещается, хотя вообще не используется. Странно, но спасибо за науку. Но для полей класса всё таки мой метод годится. :)

Comment: `Но для полей класса всё таки мой метод годится.` И вы это проверили на всех существующих компиляторах? И гарантируете, что ваш способ продолжит работать в будущем на новой версии компилятора? Стандарт языка, например, таких гарантий не даёт. В принципе, уже сейчас в некоторых специфических ситуациях ваш метод [не работает](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97e0a24828c477c5).

Comment: Насчёт якобы "специфической ситуации" возражаю. constexpr - это расчёты на этапе компиляции, и в constexpr-функциях прямо запрещено приведение типов указателей. Зато этот пример отлично показал, что компайлер прекрасно видит все эти трюки. Так что да, гарантировать работоспособность можно, так как расконстантивание через указатели используется для доступа к полям сплошь и рядом, когда необходимо достучаться до закрытых областей чужого кода, который нельзя менять (внешние либы, например) Я согласен, что это моветон и небезопасно, но это реальная жизнь, и разрабы компайлеров не рискнут спорить.

Comment: `в constexpr-функциях прямо запрещено приведение типов указателей.` Снятие константности разрешено, и [это работает](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de1cff4bab61d989). И судя по тексту ошибки, в предыдущем примере компилятор не устраивает не приведение типа указателя, а именно модификация  константного объекта: `modifying a const object is not allowed in a constant expression`. `компайлер прекрасно видит все эти трюки ... достучаться до закрытых областей чужого кода ... внешние либы, например` Это совершенно разные ситуации...

Comment: ...Одно дело, когда компилятор не знает наверняка является ли объект константным на самом деле (константность указателя не гарантирует константность объекта), а потому _вынужден предполагать_, что он может быть не константным, и совсем другое, когда компилятор смог на этапе компиляции доказать, что объект гарантированно константный. `разрабы компайлеров не рискнут спорить` [Печальная история о `memcpy` и UB](https://avva.livejournal.com/2323823.html), которую полезно перечитывать, когда возникает мысль, что «разрабы не рискнут спорить потому, что это используется сплошь и рядом».